# jQuery Accordion Grid that opens full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery Accordion and my problem is two-fold.

1. When you click on the persons name to close the div (after you've clicked to open it) it closes then slides the whole window up. I don't want it to slide the whole window up.
2. When you click on the person's image to open the div and then click to close it, the div closes but then opens again right away and the whole window slides up.

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do something...
    function close_accordion_section() {
jQuery('.accordion .accordion-item .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
}

  jQuery('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
// Grab current anchor value
var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

if(jQuery(e.target).is('.active')) {
  close_accordion_section();
}else {
  close_accordion_section();

  // Add active class to section title
  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
  // Open up the hidden content panel
  jQuery('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
}

e.preventDefault();
});
});
});
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="accordion"><!-- THUMBNAIL -->
<div class="accordion-item">
<a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="First Last" width="150" height="150" />
</a>

<span class="accordion-section-name">
<a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">First Name</a></span>
<span class="accordion-section-expertise">Expertise</span>
</div>
<!--end .accordion-item-->
<!-- ABOUT -->

<div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
<div class="advisors">
<ul class="advisors">
    <li>Marketing and Communications</li>
    <li>Sales and Business Development</li>
    <li>Finance</li>
    <li>Startup Strategy</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="about">
 <p class="about">About</p>
 Biography
 </div>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Edited to add new function:

```
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do something...
    function close_accordion_section() {

jQuery('.accordion .accordion-item .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
}

  jQuery('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 

var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
   currentAttrValue = currentAttrValue.substring(1, currentAttrValue.length);

jQuery("#" + currentAttrValue).slideToggle();


  });
    }); 
return false;   
     });
```

This entire window is still sliding up for me.

Comment: You just want to slide the "#accordion-1" content right? i.e. if it is open, close that. and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

add `return false;` after `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you,

```
jQuery('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
       currentAttrValue = currentAttrValue.substring(1, currentAttrValue.length);

    jQuery("#" + currentAttrValue).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: This stopped the div from reopening when the image is clicked! Thank you! The whole window still slides up though after the div has closed. Although, I am using this function on several pages, and not all of them have the name portion only the image. And on those pages the div isn't opening at all now. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry ignore the last sentence there. On those pages, there isn't an accordion (my bad) but I am using the same classes to style them, and they are not linking to their outside respective pages. I suppose I could try changing the classes though

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that the click event on the anchor element is not being stopped and because of which the page tries to navigate to the `id` of the element passed as `href` param, and hence it scrolls up.

So you should try stopping the click event from `bubbling up`.

So either you can use `e.preventDefault();`  or `return false;`

As shown in this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/ezzwPv).

Comment: Hi Mohd, I am now using the function below your comment here from Samir, and he has included e.preventDefault(); which doesn't seem to have the effect you're describing. Return False seems to stop anything from happening at all. (The div doesn't open) Any ideas?

Comment: Then `return false` at the end of the function, after you have completed your logic.

Comment: hmm ok that isn't working for me. Maybe I am not adding it in the right place?